# Better way to check against an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm working through a tic tac toe game and have really hit a wall with how to simplify some checks. Below you will find a horizontal, vertical and diagonal checks to see whether a player has won.

**Question:** What can I use to simplify this without repeating so much code? Any guidance in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

The array looks like this:

```
gridArray: [
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', ''],
  ]
```

The playerTurn variable just changes from x to o as you play.

```
// Horizontal check
state.gridArray.map((item, index) => {
  if(
    item[0] === playerTurn &&
    item[1] === playerTurn &&
    item[2] === playerTurn) {
    console.log(playerTurn + ' has won!');
  }
});



// Vertical check
if(
  state.gridArray[0][0] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[1][0] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[2][0] === playerTurn
) {
  console.log(playerTurn + ' has won!');
}

if(
  state.gridArray[0][1] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[1][1] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[2][1] === playerTurn
) {
  console.log(playerTurn + ' has won!');
}

if(
  state.gridArray[0][2] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[1][2] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[2][2] === playerTurn
) {
  console.log(playerTurn + ' has won!');
}



// Diagonal check
if(
  state.gridArray[0][0] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[1][1] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[2][2] === playerTurn
) {
  console.log(playerTurn + ' has won!');
}

if(
  state.gridArray[0][2] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[1][1] === playerTurn &&
  state.gridArray[2][0] === playerTurn
) {
  console.log(playerTurn + ' has won!');
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not a `for` loop?

Comment: Do you want to stick to  this data structure? Or can we propose another one?

Comment: 4castle - I'm just not sure how to structure the for loop to return the same as above. trincot - I'd be more than happy to try another data structure, what did you have in mind?

Comment: @MarioD, I have answered with the slightly different data structure.

Comment: If you have working code, you can instead visit Code Review, which even has a tag for [improving tic tac toe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a slightly different data structure, with just 1 dimension, and numerical content. You could then define another variable that lists all triplet indexes in that structure that represent a win. With that set up, the function to detect a win becomes almost a one-liner:

```
var gridArray = [
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0,
]; 

var lines = [
    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8],
    [0,3,6],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [0,4,8],
    [2,4,6]
];

function hasWon(gridArray, lines, playerTurn) {
    return lines.some(line => line.every(cell => gridArray[cell] === playerTurn));
}
```

Note: the numerical values in the grid would become 1 for 'X' and 2 for 'O'. It is easy with a string `display = [' ', 'X', 'O']` to convert one to the other.

#### Alternative

If you really want to get efficient code, you could revert to bit manipulation, and represent the grid with two integers, one for the 'X' positions and one for the 'O' positions. You would use 9 bits of each integer. With the same principle you would define all the bit masks that make up a win, and do an `&` with these to see if you have a match.

```
var gridArray = [0b000000000, 0b000000000]; // X bits, O bits

var lines = [
    0b111000000,
    0b000111000,
    0b000000111,
    0b100100100,
    0b010010010,
    0b001001001,
    0b100010001,
    0b001010100
];

function hasWon(gridArray, lines, playerTurn) {
    return lines.some(line => (line & gridArray[playerTurn]) == line);
}
```

Comment: The grid doesn't necessarily have to be numerical. It could still be 'X' & 'O' for the first solution.

Comment: True, I just think it is better to use numbers: it should be faster for the win-check. Thanks for having corrected some typos!

Comment: `==` is evaluated before `&`. I think you need some parentheses.

Comment: I like this solution, however you'd probably need 4 items in `gridArray`, two for X, two for Y, otherwise you don't know the empty spaces. Also, unless you can generate them progmatically, the list of winning combinations starts to become unmaintainable if it was to be applied to other similar games, e.g. connect 4 :(

Comment: The empty spaces are derived by a simple `|` of the two: what is 0 is empty. Indeed this is not suitable for larger games. Imagine GO. :-)

Comment: @trincot ah I was thinking in 3 bits instead of 9! .. Solve this for GO in as many chars and you'd win your choice of computing award.

Comment: I see I caused that confusion by speaking at one point of X and Y in my answer instead of 'X' and 'O'. Corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

Using a nested `for`, this function would be able to look at the game in any state and tell you if and whom the winner is by counting up the number of Xs and Os

```
function whoWon(grid) {
    var i, j,
        rX, rO,
        cX, cO,
        ddX, ddO,
        duX, duO;
    ddX = ddO = duX = duO = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        rX = rO = cX = cO = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            if (grid[i][j] === 'x') ++rX;
            else if (grid[i][j] === 'o') ++rO;

            if (grid[j][i] === 'x') ++cX;
            else if (grid[j][i] === 'o') ++cO;
        }
        if (grid[i][i] === 'x') ++ddX;
        else if (grid[i][i] === 'o') ++ddO;

        if (grid[2 - i][i] === 'x') ++duX;
        else if (grid[2 - i][i] === 'o') ++duO;
    }
    if (Math.max(rX, cX, ddX, duX) === 3) return 'x';
    if (Math.max(rO, cO, ddO, duO) === 3) return 'o';
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a String to check the value of 'X' or 'O' you could try to use a numeric value, like 1 and 4, this way sum the values for every axis. then if its value is 0 then there are no moves in that axis, and if the value is 3 that axis has a winning move for 'X' and if its value is 12 its a winning move for 'O'.

thx @4castle for pointing that, it would indeed be a false positive i did the correction

Comment: What if the pattern was `[1, 2, 0]`? That would give a false positive for X. 1 & 2 won't work. 1 & 4 do though.

Answer (score 0):

## Bitboards & lookup table

One of the most efficient ways of testing winning positions would be to use [**bitboards**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard) and a lookup table.

Bitboards are of common use in Chess engines where each bit of a 64-bit integer is describing a given property of a square, such as *'a white piece is on this square'* or *'a bishop is on this square'*.

For Tic-Tac-Toe, we only need two bitboards to describe the game: one for the 'X' side and one for the 'O' side. Each bitboard consists of 9 bits:

```
8 7 6     // where 8 is the most significant bit
5 4 3     // and 0 is the least significant bit
2 1 0     // (we could do it the other way around just as well)
```

Let's see how a position is encoded, here for the 'X' side:

```
X . X     1 0 1
. X .  =  0 1 0  =  101010011 in binary  =  0x153 in hexadecimal
. X X     0 1 1
```

Now, let's encode all winning configurations:

```
X X X   . . .   . . .   X . .   . X .   . . X   X . .   . . X
. . .   X X X   . . .   X . .   . X .   . . X   . X .   . X .
. . .   . . .   X X X   X . .   . X .   . . X   . . X   X . .
0x1C0   0x038   0x007   0x124   0x092   0x049   0x111   0x054
```

There are only 2^9 = 512 possible positions for a given side (including some that are actually impossible to reach). Therefore, it is perfectly feasible to build a lookup table with all 512 positions, that will tell us if it's a win or not:

```
var winMask = [ 0x1C0, 0x038, 0x007, 0x124, 0x092, 0x049, 0x111, 0x054 ],
    isWin = [];

for(var n = 0; n < 512; n++) {
  isWin[n] = winMask.some(function(msk) { return (n & msk) == msk; });
}
```

Now, we can just do something like:

```
if(isWin[xBoard]) {
  console.log('X has won!');
}
```

Of course, this is a bit overkill for such a simple game, but the same ideas would applied to a more sophisticated one.

Besides, if you'd like to implement a 'human vs computer' version, your AI could use `isWin[]` to quickly evaluate the outcome of the game on the leaf nodes of the search tree.

## Implementation

Below is a simple implementation of the whole game using the technique we've just described.

Here, you can see two other operations that are easily achieved with bitboards:

- check whether a cell is empty: `!((board[0] | board[1]) & msk)`
- check whether the entire board has been filled: `(board[0] | board[1]) == 0x1ff`

```js
var winMask = [ 0x1C0, 0x038, 0x007, 0x124, 0x092, 0x049, 0x111, 0x054 ],
    isWin = [],
    board, player;

for(var n = 0; n < 512; n++) {
  isWin[n] = winMask.some(function(msk) { return (n & msk) == msk; });
}

$('button').click(function() {
  var msk = 0x100 >> $('button').index(this);

  if(!((board[0] | board[1]) & msk)) {
    $(this).html('XO'[player]);
    board[player] |= msk;
    
    if(isWin[board[player]]) {
      alert('XO'[player] + ' has won!');
      newGame();
    }
    else if((board[0] | board[1]) == 0x1ff) {
      alert('This is a draw!');
      newGame();
    }
    else {
      player ^= 1;
    }
  }
});
newGame();

function newGame() {
  board = [ 0, 0 ];
  player = 0;
  $('button').html('.');
}
```

```css
button { width:32px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button></button><button></button><button></button></div>
<div><button></button><button></button><button></button></div>
<div><button></button><button></button><button></button></div>
```